# Slow down Slieder [owl-carousel]

Tags: owl-carousel

I try every way and I can't slow down the slide change. The change takes about 4-5 seconds. Platform: Wordpress.

Code in CSS:

```
.owl-carousel, .owl-carousel .owl-item {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative
}


.owl-carousel {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1
}


.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    position: relative;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden
}


.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}


.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item, .owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
}


.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled, .owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled {
    display: none
}


.no-js .owl-carousel, .owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
    display: block
}


.owl-carousel .owl-dot, .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next, .owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}


.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next, .owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev, .owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
    background: 0 0;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font: inherit
}


.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block
}


.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
    opacity: 0
}


.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
    visibility: hidden
}


.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}


.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grab
}


.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
    direction: rtl
}


.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
    float: right
}


.owl-carousel .animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both
}


.owl-carousel .owl-animated-in {
    z-index: 0
}


.owl-carousel .owl-animated-out {
    z-index: 1
}


.owl-carousel .fadeOut {
    animation-name: fadeOut
}


.keyframes fadeOut {
    0%

{
    opacity: 1
}


.00% {
    opacity: 0
}


..owl-height {
    transition: height .5s ease-in-out
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s ease
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy:not([src]), .owl-carousel .owl-item .owl-lazy[src^=""] {
    max-height: 0
}


.owl-carousel .owl-item img.owl-lazy {
    transform-style: preserve-3d
}


.owl-carousel .owl-video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000
}


.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    background: url(owl.video.play.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .1s ease
}


.owl-carousel .owl-video-play-icon:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3,1.3)
}


.owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-play-icon, .owl-carousel .owl-video-playing .owl-video-tn {
    display: none
}


.owl-carousel .owl-video-tn {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: opacity .4s ease
}


.owl-carousel .owl-video-frame {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Trial and error method